# Devolver cantidad de filas para paginar Mysql

Tags: mysql

Tengo el siguiente metodo que retorna una Tabla con un filtro de busqueda, y se me ocurrio agregarle paginacion.

```
        public DataTable Listado_pr(string cTexto,int pagina,int cantidad)
        {
            MySqlDataReader Resultado;
            DataTable Tabla = new DataTable();
            MySqlConnection SQLCon = new MySqlConnection();

            try
            {
                SQLCon = Conexion.getInstancia().CrearConexion();
                MySqlCommand Comando = new MySqlCommand("USP_Listado_pr", SQLCon);
                Comando.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                Comando.Parameters.Add("cTexto", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = cTexto;
                Comando.Parameters.Add("pagina", MySqlDbType.Int32).Value = pagina;
                Comando.Parameters.Add("registros", MySqlDbType.Int32).Value = cantidad;
                SQLCon.Open();
                Resultado = Comando.ExecuteReader();
                Tabla.Load(Resultado);
                return (Tabla);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                throw ex;
            }
            finally
            {
                if (SQLCon.State == ConnectionState.Open) SQLCon.Close();
            }
        }
```

el caso es que quiero devolver con count(*) de MySQL la cantidad total de registros de la consulta sea con filtros o no para obtener la cantidad de paginas de acuerdo a la cantidad de registros por pagina que se desea mostrar.

Mi sp es asi:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `USP_Listado_pr`(IN cTexto varchar(100),pagina int,registros int)
begin 

declare inicio int;              
declare fin int;
set inicio=(pagina - 1) * registros +1;
set fin=(inicio + registros -1)/pagina;

IF (cTexto!="") THEN  
 select distinct count(*),a.codigo_pr,    
   a.codigo_an,
  a.codigo_barra,
  a.descripcion_pr,    
  b.descripcion_ma,    
  c.descripcion_um,    
  d.descripcion_ca,    
  a.stock_min,    
  a.stock_max,    
  a.codigo_ma,    
  a.codigo_um,    
  a.codigo_ca,

  a.pu_venta  
 from tb_productos             a       
 inner join tb_marcas           b on a.codigo_ma=b.codigo_ma    
 inner join tb_unidades_medidas c on a.codigo_um=c.codigo_um    
 inner join tb_categorias       d on a.codigo_ca=d.codigo_ca    
 where a.estado=1 and   (      
 upper(    
    trim(a.descripcion_pr)  
 ) like CONCAT('%',upper(trim(cTexto)),'%')     or
 (    
    a.codigo_barra=cTexto  ) or 
    TRIM(a.codigo_an)like concat('%',upper(trim(cTexto )),'%')     )
order by a.codigo_pr  limit inicio,fin ; 
ELSE
 select count(*),a.codigo_pr,   
    a.codigo_an,
  a.codigo_barra,
  a.descripcion_pr,    
  b.descripcion_ma,    
  c.descripcion_um,    
  d.descripcion_ca,    
  a.stock_min,    
  a.stock_max,    
  a.codigo_ma,    
  a.codigo_um,    
  a.codigo_ca,  
  a.pu_venta  
 from tb_productos              a       
 inner join tb_marcas           b on a.codigo_ma=b.codigo_ma    
 inner join tb_unidades_medidas c on a.codigo_um=c.codigo_um    
 inner join tb_categorias     d on a.codigo_ca=d.codigo_ca    
 where a.estado=1  
order by a.codigo_pr limit inicio,fin  ; 
END IF;

end
```

Y no me funciona (devuelve 0 filas) tengo entendido porque count no se puede usar con limit, cual seria una solucion para devolver ambos valores sin ejecutar la sentencia 2 veces?